# Unresolved reference: databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, android-gradle, android-data-binding

Вылетает ошибка:

```
Unresolved reference: databinding
```

Почему, не могу понять, вроде все нужные зависимости добавил

`build.gradle(Project)`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle(Module)`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sem.receivedata"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    def room_version = '2.4.3'
    def lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"
    def coroutines_version = '1.6.4'
    def koin_version = '3.2.0'

    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    // Koin main features for Android (Scope,ViewModel ...)
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    // Koin Java Compatibility
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android-compat:$koin_version"
}
```

`layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presrntation.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cat_fragment"
        android:name="com.sem.receivedata.presrntation.NameListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</layout>
```

`MainActivity`:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.sem.receivedata.R
import com.sem.receivedata.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поменял разметку на:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presrntation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cat_fragment"
        android:name="com.sem.receivedata.presrntation.NameListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

И всё заработало